# how to remove index value in for loop (that is 0)

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0;i<11;i++)
{
    table.insertRow(i);     
    var cell2 = table.rows[i].insertCell(-1);
    var cell4 = document.createTextNode(i);
    cell2.appendChild(cell4);                        
}
```

[image: here is the image]

Comment: Start your for loop from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Please go through this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1):

```
for i = 1
```

Just start at 1 instead of at 0, then you skip the 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for(i=1;i<11;i++) { table.insertRow(i);
var cell2 = table.rows[i].insertCell(-1); var cell4 = document.createTextNode(i); cell2.appendChild(cell4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
 for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {

 }
```